# Building query for search engine

Tags: ruby, sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, active-record

I'm writing a basic search engine for my website.

It works but I'm really unhappy with the code. I know it can't be improved but I'm lacking some experiences here.
In my params from my search I get:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aNY2ZVpeyZsLnIVegQPpPz/22VYx2ug+tbfu0Nzngac=", "skills"=>"3,8", "country"=>"USA", "state"=>"TX", "city"=>"Paris", "commit"=>"Search", "controller"=>"jobs", "action"=>"index"}
```

Here is my controller:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index]

  def index
    search_jobs
  end

  def search_jobs
    search_filters = search_params
    if search_filters.present?
      skills = search_filters[:skills]
      city, state, country = search_filters[:city], search_filters[:state], search_filters[:country]
      search_jobs = Job.select(:id).joins(:skills)
      search_jobs = search_jobs.where(build_where(skills)) if skills.present?
      search_jobs = search_jobs.group("jobs.id")
      search_jobs = search_jobs.group("jobs.city, jobs.state") if city.present? || state.present?
      search_jobs = search_jobs.group("jobs.created_at")
      search_jobs = search_jobs.order("city <> '#{city}'") if city.present?
      search_jobs = search_jobs.order("state <> '#{state}'") if state.present?
      search_jobs = search_jobs.order("country <> '#{country}'") if country.present?
      search_jobs = search_jobs.order("count(*) desc")
      search_jobs = search_jobs.order('jobs.created_at DESC')
      jobs_id = search_jobs.map(&:id)
    end
    jobs = Job.includes(:company, :skills)
    jobs = jobs.where(id: jobs_id) if jobs_id.present?
    jobs = jobs.most_recent
    @jobs = jobs
  end

  def build_where(skills_filters)
    skills = skills_filters.split(", ")
    query = "'skills'.'id' = #{skills.first}"
    skills.shift
    skills.each do |skill| 
      query << " OR 'skills'.'id' = #{skill}"
    end
    return query
  end

  private

  def search_params
    params.permit(:skills, :country, :city, :state)
  end

end
```

Few, things:

- I'm not happy with the build_where method, but I can't think of a way to build a where dynamically based on the skills the users are looking for.
- The search_jobs seems the be a bad idea. When I run this in the developer console it looks like each line is executing a SQL query which is an issue performance wise. 10 queries  to get a list of IDs seems to be terrible
- Then I'm doing 3 more queries afterward: to get all the jobs with all the information needed.

So, I think my code is not really good, but I'm not sure how I can improve it. My goal overall is

Answer (score 4):

There are some bugs related to parameter handling:

- **Splitting by `", "`:** In `#build_where`, you split the `skill` parameter by `", "`.  However, you example has just `"skills"=>"3,8"` — with no space after the comma.  Splitting will therefore fail.
- **SQL injection vulnerability:** Parts of the value of the `skills` parameter end up in the SQL query's `WHERE` clause, but you never validated, escaped, or parameterized the query.  You use the `city`, `state`, and `country` parameters with similar carelessness, interpolating values directly into an `ORDER BY` clause.  If a user tries to specify `St. John's` as the city, the query will break due to the apostrophe being treated as a quotation mark.  A malicious user can exploit that to do [nasty things to your database](http://bobby-tables.com).

  [image: "Did you really name your son Robert'); DROP TABLE Student;--?" "Oh. Yes. Little Bobby Tables, we call him." "Well we've lost this year's student records. I hope you're happy."]

---

I also suspect that

> ```
> Job.select(:id).joins(:skills)
> ```

is the wrong thing to do.  That produces an `INNER JOIN`.  Any job that has no special required skills will therefore not appear in the join result.  I'm guessing that a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` would be more appropriate.

---

As for the skills filter itself, the `WHERE` clause you want in SQL is

```
WHERE "skills"."id" IN (3, 8)
```

(Writing `'skills'.'id'` results in much brokenness.  To quote identifiers in PostgreSQL, use double-quotes.  Single quotes are used to quote literal strings, not identifiers.)

I would therefore write it as

```
def restrict_skills(search_jobs, skills_filters)
  # Check for non-empty string consisting only of digits, commas, and spaces
  if skills_filters.match(/\A[0-9, ]+\Z/)
     search_jobs.where(%Q{"skills"."id" IN (#{skills_filters})})
  end
end
```

Usually, I recommend parameterizing queries.  Escaping is my second choice.  Validating is normally my third choice.  However, here I've used validation instead of parameterizing and escaping because validation is easy: just check that the `skills` parameter consists of just digits, commas, and spaces.  It also happens that the SQL `IN` clause expects comma-delimited integers here.

I've also changed the helper method to manipulate the query-building object rather than to return a fragment of SQL.

Comment: thanks a lot. Regarding `INNER JOIN`, I want to display only the jobs that have the required skills in the params. So I'm guessing that .joins(:skills) is correct. For the `WHERE "skills"."id" IN (3, 8)` this will on return the jobs with skills 3 and 8 but I want jobs with skills 3 or 8.

Comment: `WHERE id IN (3, 8)` is equivalent to `WHERE id=3 OR id=8`.